# Многопоточная программа C++

Tags: c++

Ищу пример простой многопоточной программы на c++(Без WinAPI)
Как то так...

```
int main() {

    запуск потока1(функция0);

    запуск потока2(функция1);

}
```

Comment: Без WinAPI это POSIX pthreads в \*nix-ах.

Посмотрите [man pthread_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html). Там даже какой-то пример есть.

Comment: Ваш вариант тоже работает. Спасибо. Но что использовать лучше?

Comment: @avengerweb, скажу сразу -- программы с C++ `thread` я не писал. 

Сейчас [посмотрел](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/multithreading/) и многих вещей, доступных в pthreads не нашел (может плохо искал).   

Посмотрите, например, [pthread_attr_init](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_init.3.html) или [pthread_rwlock_init](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_rwlock_init) и решайте сами.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Совсем-совсем без WinAPI не получится, «внутри» реализация потоков под Windows будут всё равно ссылаться на WinAPI. Кроссплатформенный способ примерно такой:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void f1() { /* чё-то делаем */ }
void f2() { /* и тут чё-то делаем */ }

int main()
{
    thread t1(f1); // запустили f1 в отдельном потоке
    thread t2(f2); // ... и f2

    t1.join();          // дождались, пока f1 отработает
    t2.join();          // дождались, пока f2 отработает

    cout << "done" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: g++ prog.cpp -std=gnu++11 -pthread
пошла только так, но пошла. Спасибо.

Comment: @avengerweb: Да, это фича C++11.

Answer (score 2):

Можно также повтыкать в [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread.html), если не ошибаюсь, то именно она была включена в С++11.